# Easier way use CSS grid-template-areas to span multiple columns

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I really love the simplicity and ease of manipulation of `grid-template-areas`, but is there an easier way/shortcut to indicate an area spans multiple columns (say 12) — within the template?

This starts to get pretty gross when you have 12 columns...

```
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav cont cont cont cont cont cont cont cont cont cont";

  @media all and (max-width: 839px){
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav nav cont cont cont cont";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine it with `grid-template-columns` like this:

```
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav cont";
  grid-template-columns:2fr 10fr;

  @media all and (max-width: 839px){
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav cont";
    grid-template-columns:1fr 4fr;
  }
}
```

Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "nav cont";
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 10fr;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.cont {
  grid-area: cont;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

@media all and (max-width: 839px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: "nav cont";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
  </div>
  <div class="cont">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok. I guess I have to look at column designation differently, rather than rigid column designations like in the Foundation or bootstrap framework. I don't always know the amount of columns certain elements should/will span.  Thanks!

Comment: it's be awesome if there was a template-area shortcut where you could append something like `"nav nav cont---"` where the `---` indicates the cont should span to the end... or something similar

Answer (score 4):

Named areas are just shortcuts for named lines, and so you can use either.  For example, your 12-column code can instead be written as:

```
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [nav-start] repeat(2, auto) [nav-end cont-start] repeat(10, auto) [cont-end];
}
```

The `-start` and `-end` line names define named areas in the same way that `grid-template-areas` does, and are sometimes more convenient to use.

(That said, I recommend usually doing what @temani-afif said, and instead just having two meaningful columns, using `fr` units to designate their relative sizes. Literal 12-column grids are an artifact of the old limitations that grid systems had to work in. But on the other hand, using actual multiple columns *is* sometimes clearer, especially if you're using gaps between the columns. Do whatever works best for you.)

Comment: thanks! this was very helpful too! Yea I'm starting to love css grid but it can get a bit messy once you start having nested grids. Easy to manage, though.