# Is there a shorter way of defining grid-template-areas?

Tags: css, css-grid

Defining areas makes setting up a CSS grid a lot easier. One defines a `grid-area` for each item that will be in the grid, and then one adds that area to `grid-template-areas`. When one has a rather complex setup for a grid, one needs to put all the grid-areas in `grid-template-areas` like this:

```
grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header header header header"
    "aside aside content content content content"
    "box1 box1 box1 box2 box3 box3"
    "box4 box5 box5 box6 box6 box6";
```

This might be a totally ignorant question, but is there a way to use something like `repeat(6, header)` or so that would shorten up the way when defining a complex area structure like this? Within a string, that's not going to work, as a group of strings is what `grid-template-areas` expects.

I know one can accomplish a comparable behavior with `grid-template-columns`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359428/easier-way-use-css-grid-template-areas-to-span-multiple-columns), where one can define a few areas, to then repeat these over a matching amount of fractional units (fr), but a structure like this wouldn't be applicable in my case, as my grid here is too complex to apply this to, or is it?

In SASS, one can loop through a variable, but I don't think that could be a way to go, would it?

Comment: you can set only a grid-template-columns, ,then , instead grid-area, you may use grid-row and grid-column.to place each element. or let auto-flow do the job if the structure matches.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain CSS, the answer is no. You need to lay it all out.

The `grid-template-areas` property is designed to provide a visual structure of the grid. That's why it exists. Any shortcuts would defy its purpose.

> [§ 7.3. Named Areas: the `grid-template-areas`
>   property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-template-areas-property)
>
> The syntax of the `grid-template-areas` property provides a
>   visualization of the structure of the grid, making the overall layout
>   of the grid container easier to understand.
>
> [§ 7.4. Explicit Grid Shorthand: the `grid-template` property
>   property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grid-shorthand)
>
> Note that the `repeat()` function isn’t allowed in these track listings, as the tracks are intended to visually line up one-to-one with the rows/columns in the “ASCII art”.

Here's `grid-template-areas` in one of my websites:

[image]

Comment: but why you define the grid area if all will span the whole row? why not simply set `grid-column:1/-1` for all ?

Comment: I wrote that rule to be "future-proof". It's a 12-column grid with great flexibility for layout changes in the future at a relatively precise level. Plus, the grid areas move around on different pages. Also, take a look at row 5. It's not `1 / -1` :-) @TemaniAfif

Comment: well, I don't know how you will handle the area in different page and yes I noticed the row 5 but I thought that better have `.` if you an area will span the whole row and then simply use `grid-column:1/-1` and grid-row to define the place.

Comment: Another consideration behind my code is readability and grid visualization. The strings may be long, but they're easy to read and it's easy to visualize the grid structure. I think that will be useful during maintenance and when others are managing this code.

Answer (score 1):

One idea of optimization is to define a range, so instead of having:

```
header header header header header header
```

you do

```
header-s . . . . header-e
```

The you consider `grid-column:header-s/header-e`. You will at least reduce the redundancy.

```css
.box  {
 display:grid;
 grid-gap:5px;
 border:1px solid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header-s . . . . header-e"
    "aside aside content-s . . content-e"
    "box1-s . box1-e box2 box3 box3"
    "box4 box5 box5 box6-s . box6-e";
 }
 .box > div:first-child {
   height:50px;
   background:red;
   grid-column:header-s/header-e;
   grid-row:1;
 }
 .box > div:nth-child(2) {
   height:50px;
   background:green;
   grid-column:box1-s/box1-e
 }
 
 .box > div:nth-child(3) {
   height:50px;
   background:blue;
   grid-area:box2
 }
  .box > div:nth-child(4) {
   height:50px;
   background:orange;
   grid-area:box3
 }
   .box > div:nth-child(5) {
   height:50px;
   background:purple;
   grid-column:box6-s/box6-e;
   grid-row:4;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It may shorten the code, but it doesn't improve its readability. And it doesn't make it easier to visualize the grid, which is the purpose of `grid-template-areas`.

Comment: @Michael_B well it depend on each one. Honestly, I also don't like to see repeated naming and this kind of *range* seems better for me